# Efficient C style comparison in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Apologies if I am asking a very trivial question... But I couldn't find the answer for this.

I was reading [Bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign) page and it is using C in its code examples.
I tried test them in C# but failed from the very first one.

For exmple,

```
int v;      // we want to find the sign of v
int sign;   // the result goes here 

// CHAR_BIT is the number of bits per byte (normally 8).
sign = -(v < 0);  // if v < 0 then -1, else 0.
```

here C# fails in the last line as C# comparison returns true or false not 1 or 0.

So my question is what is the best way of implementing this type of a operation in C#?

I certainly can do `sign = -(v < 0 ? 1 : 0)` but I think it is not efficient enough.

Comment: what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: So, why exactly is `sign = -(v < 0 ? 1 : 0)` not efficient enough for you? How long does it take and what's the maximum time you are willing to spend on this operation?

Comment: @Tomas :I was just trying to see whether I could do these in C#.

Comment: How many times are you going to repeat this operation? Do you have a baseline benchmark? Do you have a performance goal in mind?

Comment: But why do you need a 0 or 1? It is more "correct" to get true or false from such an operation. Also, are you looking for performance or just a solution to the problem?

Comment: This question is in dire need of a problem description. What specific problem are you trying to solve here? I'm closing this as not-a-real-question, but if you have a more concrete problem description feel free to edit it in and flag for reopening.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear about my intention. I was looking at how to do this style of coding in C# and it is not this particular problem I was interested in. The code I quoted was just an example.

Comment: Interestingly, this is not a CLR restriction.  Boolean values are stored as integer 1 and 0 on the stack in IL; there is no OpCode to load a boolean constant and the comparison OpCodes yield I4 values.  The designers of C# chose to impose a more restrictive interpretation of the bool type (which is not necessarily a bad thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for the `int` overload of `Math.Sign()` in .NET, it looks like this:

```
public static int Sign(int value)
{
    if (value < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (value > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If it's fast enough for the BCL, it's probably fast enough for you, too.

I would also suggest just using the various overloads of `Math.Sign()` anyway, since they work on all numeric types (not just `int`s.) While it does return 1 rather than 0 when the number is positive, you can still just be *testing* for -1, so it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: A method call is much more inefficient...

Comment: @Skomski My point is just that *within* the `Sign()` method, that's how they check for the sign. And while a function call is certainly worse, that's mitigated by a) it would probably still be fast *enough* anyway, and b) this call could easily be inlined.

Comment: Thanks dlev. I was looking at how to do this style of coding in C# and it is not this particular problem I was interested in. The code I quoted was just an example.

Comment: @Herne Sure thing. As the commenters point out, that particular "hack" isn't possible in C#, since C# uses a strong boolean type, rather than relying on integers (as in C). I guess I was responding to that "what's the best way to do this in C#?" portion of the question, since I think the above code is the best way!

Answer (score 1):

C# compiler does many optimizations itself, so any of posted solutions may result in the same machine code as your example (don't forget that real machine code is emitted when the assembly is executed and may vary depending on current CPU etc.).

The most accurate translation from C to C# I could find is this:

```
sign = -Convert.ToInt32(i < 0)
```

as the C code uses implicit conversion between "boolean" and integer values. (I quoted boolean because in C all booleans are actually integers).

Though, as I've already written, such tricks are hardly to be useful in pure C#.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [Math.Sign()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd3y5wdf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method

It returns:

- -1: value is less than zero.
- 0: value is equal to zero.
- 1: value is greater than zero.